# rewrite and redirect URL without causing in a redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some URLs which i want to rewrite and redirect

`mysite.com/search2.php?search=abc`  should be redirected to `mysite.com/search/abc`.

And `mysite.com/search/abc`should show page `mysite.com/search2.php?search=abc` without changing URL.

I have written the rewrite code but can't do redirection without causing an infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)?$ search2.php?search=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ search2.php?search=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ search2.php?search=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L,QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ search2.php?search=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ file2.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ directory2.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ directory2.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What about other parameters?

Comment: the second rewrite

Comment: Sorry ,I didnt get you. Could you explain what happens when you type the url ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: error 404 as the rewrite rule with internal redirecting didn't work